# Clear or pause console in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console

In my project user should interact with program using console of IntelliJ Idea. How can I clear the console or pause it, until user will press some key?
For example in c++ there are `system ("CLS");` and `system("pause");` for this purposes.

Comment: Clear the IJ console: it's not possible. Wait until user will press some key: Scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ Idea doesn't have console like Visual Studio, it is more like console log, so you can't clear it. You can print some empty lines and it will be similar to clearing. For pausing console you can use `System.in.read();`

Comment: You can clear the console using https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console